# Breaking Flawed One Time Pad

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, block-cipher, one-time-pad

I have a cyphered OTP message and the sender made a mistake and used a key that was shorter than a message.
The plaintext was not padded before encryption so length of c equals length of m.

- How could I calculate the length of the OTP key (k) used to encrypt the message based on the given information?

I am new to this field so I am wrapping my head around it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you encrypt a 20 byte message with a 15 byte OTP, what would you expect to see as the output?

Comment: A not-so-secure cipher? @rossum